# How to change default port

Tags: docker, openmaptiles

I can't start my openmaptiles servers because the 8080 port is already in use:

```
root@server:# docker run --rm -it -v $(pwd):/data -p 8080:80 klokantech/openmaptiles-server
Unable to find image 'klokantech/openmaptiles-server:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from klokantech/openmaptiles-server
cc1a78bfd46b: Pull complete
6861473222a6: Pull complete
7e0b9c3b5ae0: Pull complete
3ec98735f56f: Pull complete
9b311b87a021: Pull complete
c74794776f5f: Pull complete
c758c9cba8be: Pull complete
70ebd5cc398c: Pull complete
2a80cb537328: Pull complete
9bb836d41778: Pull complete
bf0ada4238ee: Pull complete
31c6ecc8b3bb: Pull complete
fd0f97a72e6a: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:d307e12ddcd950e1bfdfc0a146d44f4818b507a56e0b00a05203c4e6166bd254
Status: Downloaded newer image for klokantech/openmaptiles-server:latest
docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint focused_noyce (a51d077ffb1f557cecd0ce1a3de05d85fe4974a8aa787d6ba56462273d221ebc): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:8080: bind: address already in use.
```

8080 is a too common port used by other apps like gitlab or for test http servers. How can i change openmaptiles config to another port?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`docker run` command has a [clear explanation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports) on that topic.

```
docker run ..... -p 9276:80 ......
```

Now your container will listen on `9276` port.